# How to setup Visual Studio to respect folders in the PYTHONPATH?

Tags: python, anaconda, visual-studio-2017

I have a Visual Studio python project and I would like to use IntelliSense to help me when working with files from a folder I added to the User-Account `PYTHONPATH`. In iPython I can use tab completion for this folder without issues. However, in VisualStudio it keeps telling me that IntelliSense may be missing for the module I try to include.

Are there any settings I have to set for Visual Studio to include those folders added to `PYTHONPATH`?

- Visual Studio 2017
- Anaconda 4.3.0
- Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

There is a setting in: `Tools > Options > Python Tools > Ignore system-wide python path`.

Although this appears to have no effect for me, I think this is the option which would do what we both want.

When using a visual studio ipython terminal

```
import os

print(os.environ['PYTHONPATH'])
```

A key error is raised, while with a normal ipython terminal outside of VS, the path is correctly printed.

Comment: Even though it seems to have fixed here(https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/pull/3150) but I still see the problem  with VS 15.5.6 which has Python 3.0.17320.1 installed.

Comment: From my expierence I cannot recommend VS for python development. VS-code however does a great job.

Comment: I just gave VS for python a go yesterday. Instantly found some issues that I believe are not me doing theings wrong but VS being in my way: pythonpath for folder based project, pythonpath in interactive windows doesn't honow project path when using virtual env. venv stuff is quite confusing and did not work as expected (envs only visible after reopening, for example). tests don't show up in TestExplorer.
And that's after one evening. I probably will go back to VS code.
Being a good citizen, I might report the issues but it is unlikely VS will have the better coding experience anytime soon.