# Why can't the python in visual studio read the PYTHONPATH environment variable

Tags: python, visual-studio

I'm a freshman to python and I'm used to using it in visual studio. However,I was encountered with a problem as the title recently.

I have set PYTHONPATH environment variable as the picture.

[image: PYTHONPATH]

And, of course, I can find the paths in Spyder. However, I can't find them in Visual Studio.

[image: PYTHONPATH]

Comment: _**I have set PYTHONPATH environment variable as the picture.**_, This isn't **setting** a Environment Variable, showing **using** instead.

Answer (score 0):

This question predates Visual Studio 2019, but for the latter at least, this behavior is intentional. From the [documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoThj.png):

> Visual Studio ignores the search path environment variable, however, even when the variable is set for the entire system. It's ignored, in fact, precisely because it's set for the entire system and thus raises certain questions that cannot be answered automatically: [...]

The page currently does not mention though that this behavior can be turned off in the python settings:

[image: python settings]

Unsetting the option should fix your issue.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoThj.png) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/search-paths?view=vs-2019

Comment: I just noticed there is also https://stackoverflow.com/a/45895313/4312669 describing the same problem. At the time of that post's answer, the proposed solution (same as this one) was ineffective.